# Create custom composite primary key in django

Tags: django, django-models, model

I am planning on a billing software. Now, for the bills, I need a bill-no, which I wish to be the primary key as well. This bill no has to be a combination of customer id and a auto-incrementing serial no.

For ex, if the customer id is "ABC", then I want the bill pk to be ABC1, ABC2, etc etc....

How can this be done is django. Right now I'm using sqlite, however I'm planning on using MySQL during deployment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customize save method, and generate the primary key

```
def sku(last_sku):
    sku = last_sku[:4]
    sku += str(int(last_sku[4:]) + 1).zfill(4)
    return sku;

class YourModel(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=8,primary_key==True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.sku:
            customer_id = self.customer.id
            try:
                last = YourModel.objects.filter(customer_id = customer_id).latest('sku')
                self.sku = sku(last.sku)
            except YourModel.DoesNotExist:
                self.sku = self.customer_id+"0001"
        super(YourModel,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```